# Styling Toolbar does not work using AppCompat

Tags: android, android-support-library

I am trying as best I can to style the `ActionBar` (i.e. an `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`) in my app, but it just won't work. I am following the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html) when trying to achieve this. **What I am really trying to do is to make the title color white.** It is currently displayed in black. My target API is 11.

What am I doing wrong?

**res/values/themes.xml**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base theme applied no matter what API -->
    <style name="MMTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

        <item name="android:textColor">@color/mm_dark_gray</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/mm_brown</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/mm_dark_gray</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/mm_green</item>

        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MMActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MMActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/mm_green</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MMActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/MMActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/mm_green</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MMTheme" parent="MMTheme.Base"></style>

    <!-- ActionBar style -->
    <style name="MMActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/mm_green</item>

        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MMActionBarTitleText</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="titleTextStyle">@style/MMActionBarTitleText</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <style name="MMActionBarTitleText" parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/mm_white</item>
        <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar tabs text -->
    <style name="MMActionBarTabText" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/mm_green</item>
        <!-- The textColor property is backward compatible with the Support Library -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

**The inflated `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mm_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
```

**In the `Activity`**

```
// Setup main Toolbar
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) mInflatedActivity.findViewById(R.id.mm_toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

I have tried everything I can think of and searched a lot online, but I cannot make it work. What am I missing?

Current result is (nevermind the search icon):

[image]

Adding `style="@style/MMActionBar"` to the xml properties of the `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` results in this:

[image]

Changing main parent theme to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar` does nothing.

Comment: create a toolbar layout then..And hand it over to your toolbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use this in yout layout xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/red600"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
```

*Set theme in xml itself to ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar which will make title text white.*

```
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
```

And I guess this is the right way to theme Toolbar, since according to official Android Developer blog

> Styling of Toolbar is done differently to the standard action bar, and
>   is set directly onto the view.
>
> Here's a basic style you should be using when you're using a Toolbar
>   as your action bar:
>
> ```
> <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar  
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
>     app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar" />
> ```
>
> The app:theme declaration will make sure that your text and items are
>   using solid colors (i.e 100% opacity white).

Comment: Doing this while keeping `style="@style/MMActionBar"` provides the desired colors. Is this really the way it is meant to be done? The official documentation I referenced uses `<item name="android:actionBarStyle"></item>` and so forth, which seems to do nothing. Why doesn't this work?

Comment: I can't usually get android:actionBarStyle attribute to work, when using Toolbar, so I switched to this method, and it seems like this way is very common. Just see this official Android Developer blog , and they are also using the same technique. So I guess this is the right way to do.    http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: @OP I guess, if my solution solved your issue, you should upvote and mark the answer as solved.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same problem. The following solution solved my problem. 
For this you need to make changes at two places.

1.Modify your toolbar xml like this,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
android:elevation="2dp"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TV_tool_bar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="My App Name"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

2. Modify like this in your activity file.

   ```
   Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
   setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
   getSupportActionBar().setTitle(null);
   ```

Thats it. This will make your title color white. Cheers..!

Comment: This is also a workable solution, though the `Toolbar` title is removed and handled ourselves. It seems easier if you want something else than black or white or whatever the main theme gives you in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to change colors of the letters on the toolbar:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar      
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/ColorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
android:elevation="4dp"
>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```